# Angular Firebase - merge two Observables into one

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, observable

Struggling a bit too long here. I have two tables in Firebase:

```
accounts
  LJHGGKJH
   prop1: 'val'
   prop2: 'val'
  IUYIUTJF
   prop1: 'val'
   prop2: 'val'

locations_per_account
  LJHGGKJH
   0: [1, 5, 6]
  IUYIUTJF
   0: [5, 2, 8]
```

As you see `accounts` item's unique key points to `locations_per_account` item's unique key - if they match they belongs to the same user.

Now I want to make one method in my service which would provide me observable of every account and its locations, so I could use `async` pipe in my template and extract the data.

Here I get all accounts:

```
  getAllAccounts() {
    return this.afDb.list('accounts/', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'hasAccount',
        equalTo: true
      }
    })      
  }
```

Here I get locations of particular account:

```
  getAccountLocations(optionalUid : string) {
    let uid : any;
    this.authService.authInfo$.subscribe(val => uid = val.$uid); 
    if (typeof optionalUid === 'undefined')
      return this.afDb.object('locations-per-account/' + uid);
    return this.afDb.object('locations-per-account/' + optionalUid);
  }
```

So I need to merge these streams into one and by merging I should construct the new shape of returning object.

(the order of both tables is symmetric (if thats the right word), but I am not sure if it will stay the same in the future, so i would like to check if both keys match).

Also to note - as you see, I could add locations array to every account, but I do it in separate table because I try to make my Firebase database as flat as possible, to avoid things like "Full table scan". Please advice if any thoughts - I am pretty new in building databases.

Comment: look at `obsevables.forkjoin`

Comment: ... I thought why I never saw `forkjoin` in http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html so I ` ctrl + F ` and found "An Alphabetical List of Observable Operators"...  Well thats some fun reading... Thanks @Rahul Singh

Comment: no problem. More info cam be found here too [rxjs](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/ngrx/rxjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use forkJoin to wait for both queries, then map the two sets together on id:

```
Rx.Observable.forkJoin([accounts$, locations$]).subscribe(results => {
  const [accounts, locations] = results
  const joined = accounts.map(account => { 
    return {
      id: account.id,
      prop1: account.prop1,
      prop2: account.prop2,
      locations: locations.filter(location => location.id === account.id)[0].loc            };
  })
  console.log(joined);
});
```

This presumes that Firebase is emitting a single value for each query, each of which is an array (which I think it does, from the docs).

Also presumes one account and location per id, if not then the mapping would need to get more complicated.

Here's a CodePen which simulates the scenario. [CodePen](https://codepen.io/RMatsen/pen/xXXEEB)

Answer (score 0):

so in your case, the pseudo code could look like this:

```
Observable.forkJoin([this.getAllAccounts(), this.getAccountLocations()])
   .subscribe(results => {
       console.log(results)
   }
);
```

a couple articles on managing observables: [Cory Rylan](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-multiple-http-requests-with-rxjs), [Tor](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/combining-multiple-rxjs-streams-in-angular-2.0)

Comment: Could you show how to forkJoin it in my case? :) Now I know for sure that `accounts` and `locations_per_account`  are not symmetric, so I must forkJoin only if their `$key` properties match. And loosing data is also not an option :) You have time until tomorrow :)) I hope I will solve it  then

Comment: @incognito I updated the answer, let me know how it goes

Comment: This will not work. It will return an error If I don't pass `optionalUid` to `getAccountLocations()`. I use that method as universal method for both - currently loggden in user and any other user if I pass `optionalUid` to that method

Comment: That was just the pseudo code, you can still pass optionalUId, that part is up to you